# Including Three.js in angular 14 with dependencies

Tags: angular, three.js

I am currently trying to build a web app with angular cli and using three.js to make interaction with the products interesting but some way some how, even after watching a lot of video for the solution I am not able to include three js in angular 14, it works with angular 13 but even still knowing updates with angular-three's updates, I am still not get the results. The result is to upload either .obj, .glb or any supported file into the scene.
Please is there anyone who can help me out?

```js
/* I used the three Library by installing the dependencies using ng add @angular-three/core */

// And I included everything even with the new way of including a file but still the same result, nothing. Plus errors from angular typescript.


import { NgtSobaOrbitControls } from '@angular-three/soba/controls';
import { NgtGLTFLoaderService } from '@angular-three/soba/loaders';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MeshStandardMaterial, Object3D, Mesh, PerspectiveCamera } from 'three';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-preview',
  templateUrl: './three.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./three.component.scss']
})
export class ThreeComponent implements OnInit {
  
  @Input() 
  set color(value: string) {
    this.#color = value;
    this.applyColorToMaterial(value);
  }

  #color = '';

  cupMaterial: MeshStandardMaterial | undefined;

  constructor(private gltfLoaderService: NgtGLTFLoaderService) {}

  cup$ = this.gltfLoaderService.load('assets/toyota.glb');

  cupLoaded(object: Object3D) {
    this.cupMaterial = <MeshStandardMaterial>(<Mesh>object.getObjectByName('Object_2')).material;
    this.applyColorToMaterial(this.#color);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

  controlsReady(controls: NgtSobaOrbitControls) {
    const orbitControls = controls.controls;
    orbitControls.enableZoom = false;
    // orbitControls.autoRotate = true;
    // orbitControls.autoRotateSpeed = 10;
    const camera = orbitControls.object as PerspectiveCamera;
    camera.zoom = 10.5;
    camera.position.setY(2);
    camera.position.setX(30);
  }

  applyColorToMaterial(color: string) {
    if (this.cupMaterial) {
      this.cupMaterial.color.setHex(parseInt(color.substring(1), 16));
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When you say "not getting results" what happens in the debug console? Any network or console.log info?

Comment: Ok actually, I cant get to actually start the project even with the dependencies installed

Comment: It's like the environment isnt really sorted out to begin

Comment: I think thats what I need help with

Answer (score 0):

In [this link](https://medium.com/geekculture/hello-cube-your-first-three-js-scene-in-angular-176c44b9c6c0) talk about install

```
npm install — save three
//and
npm install — save @types/three
```

It's looks like work in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-upbtho?file=tsconfig.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) with Angular 14

Comment: I have installed all the dependencies actually; with the documentation

Comment: It's looks like work in a stackblitz with Angular 14,                                                                               Yes please...